# Conjugation on the space of linear maps

Tags: linear-algebra

I am familiar with the definition of the conjugate space $V^{conj}$, given a complex vector space $V$. It is defined by
$$V^{conj}=\{\overline{v} \mid v\in V\}$$
with addition $\overline{v+u}=\overline{v}+\overline{u}$,
and scalar multiplication $\lambda\cdot \overline{v}=\overline{\bar{\lambda}v}$.

Also this construction is functorial, ie for a linear map $T:V\to W$ we define
$$T^{conj}:V^{conj}\to W^{conj}$$
by $T^{conj}(\overline{v})=\overline{T(v)}$, with this definition we get a linear map $V^{conj}\to W^{conj}$.

On the vector space $\operatorname{Hom}(V^{conj}, W^{conj})$ the scalar product is defined, as usual, by
$$\lambda\cdot_{Hom}S(\bullet)=\lambda\cdot S(\bullet)=S(\lambda\cdot\bullet)$$.

If we apply this construction on $\operatorname{Hom}(V,W)$, we will get the vector space $\operatorname{Hom}(V,W)^{conj}$.

I would like to know if there is a natural way to interpret some
$\overline{T}\in \operatorname{Hom}(V,W)^{conj}$ as a map $V\to W$.

> In particular I hope for some kind of natural isomorphism like $$\operatorname{Hom}(V^{conj}, W^{conj})^{conj}\simeq \operatorname{Hom}(V, W)$$ or maybe $$\operatorname{Hom}(V^{conj}, W^{conj})\simeq \operatorname{Hom}(V,W)^{conj} $$?

If we have in our disposal two conjugate-linear, involutions
$$\sigma: V\to V \text{ and } \sigma': W \to W$$
(ie and $\sigma(\lambda v + u)=\bar{\lambda}\sigma(v)+\sigma(u)$ and, $\sigma^2=id_V$)
what could be said?

Comment: Do you mean natural isomorphism in the categorial sense between functors? If so what functors are you considering? Or are you looking merely for an isomorphism between the two spaces?

Comment: I mean a vector space isomorphism, which could be described without any reference on a basis, or at least using a pair of conjugate-linear involutions.

Comment: So for the first part of your question: Both the isomorphisms you are looking for are the identity. You already did all the argumenation needed in the beginning of your question. Use that $(T^{conj})^{conj}=T$.

To the second part with the involutions I dont know what you are looking for?

Comment: You are saying that $(V^{conj})^{conj}\simeq V$. Ok, I see this. I am interested on how the conjugation interplay with $\operatorname{Hom}$. For example, a element of $\operatorname{Hom}(V,W)^{conj}$ could be interpreted as a map $V\to W$?